# Apache игнорирует файл .htaccess

Tags: ubuntu, apache, .htaccess

Apache игнорирует файл .htaccess. Вот собственно сам файл:

```
AuthName "secure folder"AuthType BasicAuthUserFile "/var/www/htpasswd"<Limit GET POST>require valid-user<Limit>
```

Опция AllowOverride везде all. В защищенную директорию захожу как будто .htaccess нет.

Answer (score 2):

> AuthUserFile "/var/www/htpasswd"

обычно его обозначают .htpasswd  проверь может у тебя что то не верно прописано.

> AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd нужно писать без кавычек

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Уже разобрался, пробовал и с кавычками,и без них. Проблема оказалось в лишней директории в дефолтном конфиге сайта.:) Все равно спасибо что ответил:)

Answer (score 0):

В настройках апача находите диррективу AlowOverride, если она установлена как None, меняете на All и перезапускаете апач

Comment: @dmitry, спасибо что ответили хотя и с опозданием! Уже разобрался. Проблема была не в Alowwerride она была установлена на all. Читайте комментарий к предыдущему ответу.